# How to set up a Hebrew font given as four .ttf files defining four variants: regular, bold, oblique, and bold & oblique, using babel+lualatex?

Tags: fonts, luatex, babel, hebrew, right-to-left

I have downloaded four `.ttf` font files for the Hebrew language. The files define variants of the same font. The variants are: regular, oblique, bold, and bold & oblique. My LaTeX document uses the `babel` package as the language manager, and `lualatex` as the typesetting engine. I have placed the four `.ttf` files in my working directory. How can I set things up in such a way that the following document uses my newly downloaded font?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[bidi=basic]{babel}
\babelprovide[main,import]{hebrew}
%\babelfont{rm}{?}

\begin{document}

עברית\\
ֿ\textbf{עברית}\\
\textit{עברית}\\
\textit{\textbf{עברית}}\\
\textbf{\textit{עברית}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: See the fontspec documentation (babelfont uses fontspec)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Is the `babel` command `\babelfont{rm}{MyFont.ttf}` interchangeable with `fontspec`'s `\setmainfont{MyFont.ttf}`, `\babelfont{sf}{MyFont.ttf}` with `\setsansfont{MyFont.ttf}`, and `\babelfont{tt}{MyFont.ttf}` with `\setmonofont{MyFont.ttf}`?

Comment: no, babel adds some functionality like automatically changing fonts with the script, but the fontspec options can be used in the optional argument of babelfont.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks. By the way,  the `fontspec` package has a `silent` option to drown warnings. I tried passing this option to the `babel` package to no avail. Is there a similar option for `babel`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Following [Ulrike Fischer's hint](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/665830/how-to-set-up-a-hebrew-font-given-as-four-ttf-files-defining-four-variants-reg#comment1655690_665830), here's one way of setting up a main Hebrew font using `babel`'s `\babelfont` command, when the four font files are in the `Fonts` subdirectory of the working directory, and are named `myfont-regular.ttf`, `myfont-italic.ttf`, `myfont-bold.ttf`, and `myfont-bold-italic.ttf`:

```
\babelfont[hebrew]{rm}[
   Path = Fonts/ ,
   Extension = .ttf ,
   UprightFont = *regular ,
   BoldFont = *bold ,
   ItalicFont = *italic ,
   BoldItalicFont = *bold-italic
]{myfont-}
```